# App crashes immediately on start up.. Crash in iOS9 on release only through TestFlight or Store. Distributed with Xcode 8

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios9

I have an iPhone app which is crashing on iOS9 devices only after being released through TestFlight or the App Store. The build specs are:

Deployment target 8.1
Base SDK: Latest iOS (iOS 10.1)

Before I post the crash logs I wanted to mention that this app has been on the app store for the past 2 years and has never had issues. We have done 3 updates to the app store this year with 2 of those being after iOS10 was released and there were no issues with iOS9 devices.

The odd thing is that we are using Crashlytics and it has reported over 600 crashes, each one of those a singular crash that points to either an internal apple framework or private API. I have got an iOS 9.2.1 device that is also crashing that I have pulled the logs from. They are starting to follow a trend however I need some help deciphering the cause of the crashes.

Crash 1:

```
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x22fb3af6 objc_msgSend + 22
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x22fc0f8a      objc_object::sidetable_release(bool) + 150
2   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x22fc13cc (anonymous namespace)::AutoreleasePoolPage::pop(void*) + 388
3   FrontBoardServices              0x24aebc7e -[FBSSerialQueue _performNext] + 242
4   FrontBoardServices              0x24aebf60 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 44
5   CoreFoundation                  0x2379d256 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 14
6   CoreFoundation                  0x2379ce46 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 454
7   CoreFoundation                  0x2379b1ae __CFRunLoopRun + 806
8   CoreFoundation                  0x236edbb8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 516
9   CoreFoundation                  0x236ed9ac CFRunLoopRunInMode + 108
10  UIKit                           0x279dfa16 -[UIApplication _run] + 526
11  UIKit                           0x279d9fb4 UIApplicationMain + 144
12  Where Next                      0x000a7816 main (main.m:16)
13  libdyld.dylib                   0x233a0872 start + 2
```

Crash 2:

```
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x22fb3af6 objc_msgSend + 22
1   CoreUI                          0x277e3022 -[CUICatalog _resolvedRenditionKeyFromThemeRef:withBaseKey:scaleFactor:devic    eIdiom:deviceSubtype:sizeClassHorizontal:sizeClassVertical:memoryClass:graphicsClass:graphicsFallBackOrder:] + 646
2   CoreUI                          0x277e2d98 -[CUICatalog _resolvedRenditionKeyForName:scaleFactor:deviceIdiom:deviceSubt    ype:sizeClassHorizontal:sizeClassVertical:memoryClass:graphicsClass:graphicsFallBackOrder:withBaseKeySelector:] + 284
3   CoreUI                          0x277e252a -[CUICatalog     namedLookupWithName:scaleFactor:deviceIdiom:deviceSubtype:sizeClassHorizontal:sizeClassVertical:] + 94
4   UIKit                           0x28183a2c __98-[_UIAssetManager     imageNamed:scale:idiom:subtype:cachingOptions:sizeClassPair:attachCatalogImage:]_block_invoke + 496
5   UIKit                           0x2818377e -[_UIAssetManager     imageNamed:scale:idiom:subtype:cachingOptions:sizeClassPair:attachCatalogImage:] + 230
6   UIKit                           0x2798bcd4 -[_UIAssetManager imageNamed:scale:idiom:subtype:] + 108
7   UIKit                           0x2798bc62 -[_UIAssetManager imageNamed:idiom:subtype:] + 46
8   UIKit                           0x2798bc2e -[_UIAssetManager imageNamed:idiom:] + 46
9   UIKit                           0x27e1e438 -[UIImageNibPlaceholder initWithCoder:] + 456
10  UIKit                           0x27f32180 UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 780
11  UIKit                           0x27f31e68 -[UINibDecoder decodeObjectForKey:] + 296
12  UIKit                           0x27e0a602 -[UIButtonContent initWithCoder:] + 382
13  UIKit                           0x27f32180 UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 780
14  UIKit                           0x27f3250c UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 1688
15  UIKit                           0x27f31e68 -[UINibDecoder decodeObjectForKey:] + 296
16  UIKit                           0x27e0d03c -[UIButton initWithCoder:] + 748
17  UIKit                           0x27f32180 UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 780
18  UIKit                           0x27f31e68 -[UINibDecoder decodeObjectForKey:] + 296
19  UIKit                           0x27e1d202 -[UIRuntimeConnection initWithCoder:] + 114
20  UIKit                           0x27e1d88c -[UIRuntimeEventConnection initWithCoder:] + 52
21  UIKit                           0x27f32180 UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 780
22  UIKit                           0x27f32112 UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 670
23  UIKit                           0x27f31e68 -[UINibDecoder decodeObjectForKey:] + 296
24  UIKit                           0x27e1c796 -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 1110
25  UIKit                           0x27cd6676 -[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] + 322
26  UIKit                           0x27aab9d6 -[UIViewController loadView] + 142
27  UIKit                           0x27971a0a -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 150
28  UIKit                           0x27971958 -[UIViewController view] + 24
29  UIKit                           0x281edf4a __67-[UIStoryboardEmbedSegueTemplate     newDefaultPerformHandlerForSegue:]_block_invoke + 498
30  UIKit                           0x280642d4 -[UIStoryboardSegueTemplate _performWithDestinationViewController:sender:]     + 432
31  UIKit                           0x28064102 -[UIStoryboardSegueTemplate _perform:] + 66
32  UIKit                           0x28064374 -[UIStoryboardSegueTemplate perform:] + 132
33  UIKit                           0x27971bca -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 598
34  UIKit                           0x27971958 -[UIViewController view] + 24
35  UIKit                           0x279786d0 -[UIWindow addRootViewControllerViewIfPossible] + 68
36  UIKit                           0x27975bf2 -[UIWindow _setHidden:forced:] + 278
37  UIKit                           0x279ea914 -[UIWindow makeKeyAndVisible] + 48
38  UIKit                           0x27c0f11c -[UIApplication     _callInitializationDelegatesForMainScene:transitionContext:] + 3320
39  UIKit                           0x27c12f0e -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 1570
40  UIKit                           0x27c26c14 __84-[UIApplication     _handleApplicationActivationWithScene:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke3228 + 36
41  UIKit                           0x27c103f6 -[UIApplication workspaceDidEndTransaction:] + 134
42  FrontBoardServices              0x24aebc74 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNext] + 232
43  FrontBoardServices              0x24aebf60 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 44
44  CoreFoundation                  0x2379d256 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 14
45  CoreFoundation                  0x2379ce46 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 454
46  CoreFoundation                  0x2379b1ae __CFRunLoopRun + 806
47  CoreFoundation                  0x236edbb8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 516
48  CoreFoundation                  0x236ed9ac CFRunLoopRunInMode + 108
49  UIKit                           0x279dfa16 -[UIApplication _run] + 526
50  UIKit                           0x279d9fb4 UIApplicationMain + 144
51  Where Next                      0x000e8816 main (main.m:16)
52  libdyld.dylib                   0x233a0872 start + 2
```

Crash 3:

```
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_malloc.dylib          0x2349c43a tiny_free_list_remove_ptr + 126
1   libsystem_malloc.dylib          0x2349b4d0 szone_free_definite_size + 932
2   libcache.dylib                  0x2330d6f4 cache_set_name + 20
3   CoreFoundation                  0x2372eb94 -[NSCache setName:] + 136
4   CoreUI                          0x277e2f0e -[CUICatalog _resolvedRenditionKeyFromThemeRef:withBaseKey:scaleFactor:devic    eIdiom:deviceSubtype:sizeClassHorizontal:sizeClassVertical:memoryClass:graphicsClass:graphicsFallBackOrder:] + 370
5   CoreUI                          0x277e2d98 -[CUICatalog _resolvedRenditionKeyForName:scaleFactor:deviceIdiom:deviceSubt    ype:sizeClassHorizontal:sizeClassVertical:memoryClass:graphicsClass:graphicsFallBackOrder:withBaseKeySelector:] + 284
6   CoreUI                          0x277e252a -[CUICatalog     namedLookupWithName:scaleFactor:deviceIdiom:deviceSubtype:sizeClassHorizontal:sizeClassVertical:] + 94
7   UIKit                           0x28183a2c __98-[_UIAssetManager     imageNamed:scale:idiom:subtype:cachingOptions:sizeClassPair:attachCatalogImage:]_block_invoke + 496
8   UIKit                           0x2818377e -[_UIAssetManager     imageNamed:scale:idiom:subtype:cachingOptions:sizeClassPair:attachCatalogImage:] + 230
9   UIKit                           0x28183f50 -[_UIAssetManager imageNamed:withTrait:] + 408
10  UIKit                           0x27c4e94c +[UIImage imageNamed:inBundle:compatibleWithTraitCollection:] + 172
11  UIKit                           0x27aae536 +[UIImage imageNamed:] + 110
12  Where Next                      0x000e555e -[PreferenceObject resetLocations] (PreferenceObject.m:184)
13  Where Next                      0x000e4b6e __33+[PreferenceObject sharedManager]_block_invoke (PreferenceObject.m:92)
14  libdispatch.dylib               0x23377dc2 _dispatch_client_callout + 22
15  libdispatch.dylib               0x233789b2 dispatch_once_f + 62
16  Where Next                      0x000e4980 +[PreferenceObject sharedManager] (once.h:75)
17  Where Next                      0x00102440 -[AppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] (AppDelegate.m:57)
18  Where Next                      0x002ced6a VMDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions (UIApplication+VMRuntime.m:138)
19  UIKit                           0x279e664e -[UIApplication     _handleDelegateCallbacksWithOptions:isSuspended:restoreState:] + 394
20  UIKit                           0x27c0f032 -[UIApplication     _callInitializationDelegatesForMainScene:transitionContext:] + 3086
21  UIKit                           0x27c12f0e -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 1570
22  UIKit                           0x27c26c14 __84-[UIApplication     _handleApplicationActivationWithScene:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke3228 + 36
23  UIKit                           0x27c103f6 -[UIApplication workspaceDidEndTransaction:] + 134
24  FrontBoardServices              0x24aebc74 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNext] + 232
25  FrontBoardServices              0x24aebf60 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 44
26  CoreFoundation                  0x2379d256 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 14
27  CoreFoundation                  0x2379ce46 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 454
28  CoreFoundation                  0x2379b1ae __CFRunLoopRun + 806
29  CoreFoundation                  0x236edbb8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 516
30  CoreFoundation                  0x236ed9ac CFRunLoopRunInMode + 108
31  UIKit                           0x279dfa16 -[UIApplication _run] + 526
32  UIKit                           0x279d9fb4 UIApplicationMain + 144
33  Where Next                      0x00103816 main (main.m:16)
34  libdyld.dylib                   0x233a0872 start + 2
```

The last two crashes look like they may be failing on finding an image asset... However because I cannot get this to replicate in debug mode or any form of "run" from Xcode I am stuck.

Appreciate the help community!

Answer (score 4):

The same problem occurs to my app. It crashes in iOS9 on release only through TestFlight or AppStore.
See the accepted answer https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/60919 . It works for me,and I fixed the bug.

How to resolve "ERROR ITMS-90682: Invalid Bundle - The asset catalog at 'Payload/XXXXX/Assets.car' can't contain 16-bit or P3 assets if the app supports iOS 8 or earlier."

With Xcode 8 GM, this error will occur if you include 16-bit or P3 assets in an app submission targeting iOS releases earlier then iOS 9.3. If your app requires wide color functionality you must change your Deployment Target to iOS 9.3 or later. If your app does not require wide color functionality and you wish to deploy it to older iOS versions then you should replace all 16-bit or P3 assets with 8-bit sRGB assets. You can find 16-bit or P3 assets by running “assetutil” on the asset catalog named in the error message from iTunes Connect. The following steps outline the process:

Create an Inspectable .ipa file. In the Xcode Organizer (Xcode->Window->Organizer), select an archive to inspect, click “Export...", and choose "Export for Enterprise or Ad-Hoc Deployment". This will create a local copy of the .ipa file for your app.
Locate that .ipa file and change its the extension to .zip.
Expand the .zip file. This will produce a Payload folder containing your .app bundle.
Open a terminal and change the working directory to the top level of your .app bundle cd path/to/Payload/your.app
Use the find tool to locate Assets.car files in your .app bundle as shown below: find . -name 'Assets.car'
Use the assetutil tool to find any 16-bit or P3 assets, in each Assets.car your application has as shown below. : sudo xcrun --sdk iphoneos assetutil --info /path/to/a/Assets.car > /tmp/Assets.json
Examine the resulting /tmp/Assets.json and look for any contents containing “DisplayGamut": “P3” and its associated “Name". This will be the name of your imageset containing one or more 16-bit or P3 assets.
Replace those assets with 8-bit / sRGB assets, then rebuild your app.
Update: If your Deployment Target is set to either 8.3 or 8.4 and you have an asset catalog then you will receive this same error message, even if you do not actually have 16-bit or P3 assets. In this case you will either need to lower your Deployment Target to 8.2, or move it up to 9.x.

Comment: Woah! Legendary answer. This has been the absolute bain for a few weeks now. Ill give your solution a try and let you know. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Release crashes (crashes that happen on builds sent through the App Store or TestFlight) can be tough to nail down. I had one which was crashing on `NSArray`'s `containsObject:` function, and could not reproduce it myself, or so I thought.

I did the following to reproduce the bug.

1. Went to Product -> Scheme -> Edit Scheme...
2. Clicked on the "Info" tab for my standard debug scheme
3. Changed the build configuration from "Debug" to "Release"
4. Rebuilt and ran the project

In some cases, this is not enough to reproduce a release crash. I did the next steps to reproduce it.

1. Unchecked the "Debug Executable" within that earlier Info tab on the scheme
2. Cleaned my project and build folder (Command-Shift-K and Command-Alt-Shift-K respectively)
3. Rebuilt and ran the project

Here is what it would look like on my configuration if I needed to do the same thing.

[image]

Once you are able to reproduce the crash (hopefully you can reproduce with logs), try your usual debugging methods to see where it is crashing. Play a sound when something executes, comment out lines, etc.

I unfortunately can't know your exact crash, though this method above helped me reproduce an issue 90% of our users were having and I wasn't, simply because I was building on debug before.

Comment: Hi Edwin, thanks for the awesome answer! I have tried all these methods you have mentioned. I have also attempted to increase the optimisation level of debug but to no avail. The worst part also is that it crashes before the logger has a chance to submit the crash with TestFlight. I will give it a try again changing the configuration to release. T

Comment: Sorry I couldn't help more :(. That is a tough one, though I'm sure you'll get through it!